# Blazor Server - one URL

Tags: .net, url, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to pass a parameter to page:

`www.website/{id}/{anotherID}`

`www.website.com/21/321`

I don't want user to see parameters:

`www.website.com`   or  `www.website.com/books`

I wonder if it is possible in blazor? I don't really need to pass it as a route parameter but don't know any other method.

Comment: Not a lot of detail here. How are you calling the URI? You could potentially do a post/put with a body, or use headers as 2 possible solutions. Without having more detail it is hard to surmise what you have tried or are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Any reason you don't just POST them?

Comment: you can pass values using cascading parameters it will not showup to users, but, i dont think its a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways.  Here's the DI service way.

Create a class to hold your data:

```cs
public class MyPageData
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Register it in DI Services

```cs
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyPageData>();
```

Example of use:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject MyPageData myPageData
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.GottoCounter>Go to Counter Page</button> 

@code {
    private void GottoCounter()
    {
        this.myPageData.Value = 10;
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/Counter");
    }
}
```

And Counter:

```cs
@page "/counter"
@inject MyPageData myPageData

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        currentCount = myPageData.Value;
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```